# what happen after i press enter to the web browser after typing google.com

Tags: networking

what really  happen after i press enter to the web browser after typing google.com.
where the first packet go and from there where it go . i want the detail information so some body please help me.

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/q/31468/64857

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried studying the output of `traceroute www.google.com` from the command line? This little utility will show you the exact route, hop by hop, that packets take from your local machine to a remote host. You can get some help understanding the output from [this site](http://networking.ringofsaturn.com/IP/traceroutedoc.php) or [this other site](http://www.exit109.com/~jeremy/news/providers/traceroute.html).

If you're on Windows, the equivalent command line utility is called `tracert`, and run the same way.

Or, you could use a similar online service: http://who.is/tools/traceroute/google.com/ if you're unfamiliar or uncomfortable with the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/31468/what-exactly-happens-when-you-browse-a-website-in-your-browser) question. It has a great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good place to start: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/internet-infrastructure.htm